# PHP/MYSQL How to compare a user id to info in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a `PHP/ databaseMySQL` Question.

How do I take a number that user has enter entered in a `php/html` self referencing form and compare it to the data in the database and pull the users info by just using the id number they entered and then echoing the specified users info.

But the id will be different depending on what user is trying to access the data.

For instance 
like:

```
SELECT * FROM clothes WHERE id =client id?
```

I do not know the correct syntax. I am new with `php` and `mysql`. I apologize in advance if this is too vague.

ok lets see if I can explain this better. Bob goes to a web page enters in his customer id of 45 and hits submit. It then takes his id and pulls and outputs the info related to that id for him to see.

Comment: as for the `client_id` you need to use a variable so it becomes dynamic so it will be something like this `SELECT * from clothers where id ="$client_id"`

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM clothes WHERE id ='".$client id.'";
```

Or try [googling](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=passing%20variables%20from%20php%20to%20mysql&oq=pass%20variable%20from%20php%20to%20mysq&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.12307j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

```
$id= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

  $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM clothes WHERE id='$id'");

  if ($result->num_rows) {
echo "ID exist!";
                         } 
  else
   {
     echo "ID doesnt exist!"
   }
```